# VS2017 restarts after closing - how to investigate/diagnose the reason?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, restart

I've a problem with my VS2017: after I close the Visual Studio, it reopens (restarts) again.
Then I must close this again - in most cases it is enough, but sometimes I must repeat the same 2...3 times to close it.
I found that:

- if I close VS in short time (seconds or tens of seconds) after
  starting, it closes properly.
- if I close VS in longer time (minutes or more), but without opening project/solution (only start page), sometimes it closes at first try, sometimes not.
- if I close VS with opened solution, it restarts near always :(

This strange behavior starts occuring afer installation of some additional tools, so this is probably caused by one of them.
Unfortunately, I've no idea how to investigate and diagnoze this - would you help?

UPDATE: tried to clear NuGet cache as described in post: [Visual Studio 2017 – Enterprise restarts on .Net Core Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167300/visual-studio-2017-enterprise-restarts-on-net-core-projects)
Didn't help :(

Some details:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017, version 15.9.17
- VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.17+28307.905
- Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.03761
- OS: Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro

Installed products:

- Visual C++ 2017   00370-10006-17768-AA719
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2017
- ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
- AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio   2.7.7039.21076
- Ankh.Package 2.7.7039.21076
- Subversion 1.9.5 via SharpSvn 1.9005.3940.224
- Git/LibGit2 0.24.0 via SharpGit 0.2401.1116.230
- ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.9.04012.0
- ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590
- ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012   4.0.30625.0
- ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.61435.0
- Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.9.03024.0
- Azure Data Lake Node   1.0
- Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.4.2000.0
- Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.4.2000.0
- Common Azure Tools   1.10
- Dotfuscator Community Edition   5.36.0.7050-e77ce80a6
- Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
- GitHub.VisualStudio   2.10.8.8132
- JavaScript Project System   2.0
- JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0
- Microsoft Visual C++ creators  1.0
- NuGet package manager   4.6.0
- Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.4.2000.0
- Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.4.2000.0
- Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   2.5
- Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.4.2000.0
- Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Node   1.0
- Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
- Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
- Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
- Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
- Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
- MLGen Package Extension   1.0
- C# tools 2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
- Visual Basic tools 2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
- Node.js Tools   1.4.30613.3
- Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio   8.14.20131.1
- VC for Microsoft Visual Studio   1.0
- ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
- ResourcePackage extension  1.0
- SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61906.03120
- Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
- Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
- ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
- TypeScript Tools   15.9.30718.2001
- Usługa Azure Functions i narzędzia Web Job   15.9.03024.0
- Usługa języka JavaScript   2.0
- Visual C++ for Linux Development   1.0.9.28307
- Visual F# Tools 10.2 for F# 4.5   15.8.0.0.
- Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0
- Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
- Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.28307.902

Comment: Doesn't really seem like an appropriate question for SO

Comment: SO FAQ allows questions about software developments tools, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour